# Logging from emulator with Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to debug a Cloud Function in my index.js. It looks like this:

```
exports.minutely_tick =
  functions.pubsub.topic('minutely-tick').onPublish((event) => {
    console.log('This job runs every minute');
    getData("myParameter")
    .then((data) => {
        return console.log('Data is ', data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return console.log('Error is: ', error);
      });
  });
```

I have started up the Cloud Functions Emulator, and it successfully prepares to emulate functions.

..but when I execute *minutely_tick* within the Cloud Function Emulator like this:

```
firebase > minutely_tick
```

the terminal only responds with:

```
[Function: bound ]
```

Why am I not getting the console.logs from my Cloud Function, as I normally get when the function runs on production?

Comment: What exactly are you doing in the emulator?  Please edit your question to be very specific about it.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am using the emulator to run my Cloud Functions locally and see their results / logs before deploying to production

Comment: What **exactly** are you typing into the emulator?

Comment: @DougStevenson I've added a screenshot of exactly what I'm entering into my terminal / the emulator. I enter the name of the function I want to run in the emulator, and am expecting it to return logs from the function (as it does on production) but is not working here locally via the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you're typing into the emulator isn't correct.  What you're doing is effectively telling the emulator (which is just a node REPL) to print the contents of the identifier `minutely_tick`, and that's just the name of a function.  To execute the function, you have to actually call it with arguments that it will receive.

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#invoke_pubsub_functions):

> For PubSub functions, insert your message payload in a Buffer instance
>   and add optionally data attributes as shown:
>
> ```
> // invokes a function with the JSON message { hello: 'world' } and attributes { foo: 'bar' }
> myPubsubFunction({data: new Buffer('{"hello":"world"}'), attributes: {foo: 'bar'}})
> ```

In your case, you will use the function named `minutely_tick` and pass it the payload you intend to test.

Comment: Ah, I see - I now entered something like minutely_tick({data: new Buffer('{"hello":"world"}'), attributes: {foo: 'bar'}}) and am getting logs. Thanks!